# JAXB Ant Task - Where to get JARs?

Tags: java, ant, jaxb

There is a number of sources, explaining the JAXB Ant Task. For example, Oracle itself: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/jaxb/ant.html.
Apparently however, none of the sources seem to provide the JAXB libraries, particularly **jaxb-xjc.jar**, or at least give a hint for where to download it.

The XJC JABX compiler of my JDK 1.6.0_24 is of version 2.1.10. There doesn't seem to be any JAXB library provided in the JDK.

I tried out things like the *jaxb-builder* Eclipse Plugin (http://sourceforge.net/projects/jaxb-builder), but i keep running into version conflicts.

Am i missing something out here? Any clues where i can obtain a proper v2.1.10 release of the JABX libraries, especially the Ant Task?

Thanks a lot for your comments!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The link you mention is for an ancient version of JAXB - ignore it, it's not relevant.

Java6 does come with JAXB 2.1, but doesn't (as far as I'm aware) come with any Ant tasks for XJC.  If you want to use the XJC that comes with the JDK, you need to use the `xjc.exe` command-line utility (which of course, you *can* use from Ant).

Alternatively, get the JAXB reference implementation from http://jaxb.java.net/, which does have an Ant task, or use another JAXB implementation such as MOXy, which should have comparable tools.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and hint. But where would i find the Ant Task from http://jaxb.java.net? I am searching for days and days - and fail to find it!

Comment: Oh dear... I've now found it: The downloadable JARs are infact installers, which will extract several libraries (JARs).

Comment: @noshy Thank you! I was having the exact same problem, until I read your comment. How bizarre! Hopefully my vote and my comment here will make your comment more visible.

Answer (score 1):

I use www.findjar.com

For jaxb-xjc, it returns
http://www.findjar.com/jar/com.sun.xml.bind/jars/jaxb-xjc-2.0.1.jar.html